# Displaying video title on hover in Divi Builder's Video Slider

Tags: css, wordpress

Using The Divi Video Slider Module to display a set of videos. We'd like to display the video title on hover for each video. Divi says they currently don't support this functionality, but said to check the development community for answers.

See the test page at https://work.gmmb.com/project/political. have tried to edit hover class, but hasn't worked.

There is a class at class="et_pb_video_overlay_hover" Not sure how we can use this to display the video's title from the WordPress Media Library.

Any good Divi coders who have tried this or might know a custom CSS or JS solution?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Comment: You might consider reaching out to the Divi users Facebook page for this type of question.

Answer (score 0):

A really quick workaround would be to use an `:after` pseudo-element on `class="et_pb_video_overlay_hover"`. You could put the title in `content:` like so:

```
.et_pb_video_slider_item_0 .et_pb_video_overlay_hover::after {
    content: "Title";
    // Title will be small, white and centered at the top of 
    // the video. Use other CSS properties to style your titles.
}
```

The first video is `.et_pb_video_slider_item_0`, the second video is  `.et_pb_video_slider_item_1` etc.

That is a quick solution you can implement right away.

Edit - I've just have a quick look at the Divi Video Slider module to see if it can be filtered. The code you need is located in these files:

```
/wp-content/themes/Divi/includes/builder/module/Slider.php
/wp-content/themes/Divi/includes/builder/module/SliderItem.php
```

I tried to use the **Admin Label** to set a title for each video, then print that to screen on the overlay, but it isn't accessible during render. I do see that `content_unprocessed` does contain the title:

```
["content_unprocessed":protected]=> string(339) 
"[et_pb_video_slider_item admin_title="Video Title Goes Here" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FkQuawiGWUw" ... "][/et_pb_video_slider_item]"
```

but it is protected and not directly accessible from within the render function.

I'm afraid it's going to require some long and tedious coding to get that to work. The easier solutions are to use the CSS hack above, or simply embed the title on your overlay images.

Comment: Most of the Divi modules have very little support for direct customization or filter hooks - which is a shame.